# How can I create a camera including guidelines for the user to snap the picture between?

Tags: android, android-camera, ocr, crop

I'm working with OCR using tess-two as my scanner and it works great when taking the photo, and using https://github.com/IsseiAoki/SimpleCropView to crop the image for the right numbers to be read from tess-two.

What I'd like to do is to take the second step of cropping the image out of the process, making it quicker for the user. I'm just confused on how to add my own crop rectangle area to allow the user to take a picture in.

Even something as simple as "[                  ]" with the rest of the camera surface view blacked out or dimmed, guiding the user to take the photo of the numbers in between the brackets.

Are there any good tutorials out there involving this? I've searched, but with no success. Or if anyone can point me in the right direction on how to start this that would be a big help! Thanks in advance!